# the driver file iastor.sys

Tags: drivers

For a BartPE-CD I need the driver file **iastor.sys**, but I can't find 
it neither on Intel's download site nor elsewhere on the internet.

Can anybody point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 3):

This is part of Intel storage driver, you can get it here:

[Intel Downloads](http://downloadcenter.intel.com/Filter_Results.aspx?strOSs=All&strTypes=All&ProductID=2101&OSFullName=All%20Operating%20Systems&lang=eng)

You want the 'Floppy Configuration Utility', either 64 or 32 depending on your requirements. You can just unzip this one, and iastor.sys should be right there :)

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

This link contains them.

http://www.tacktech.com/display.cfm?ttid=414

Answer (score 2):

iastor.sys is for Intel's Matrix Storage driver. Intel [mentions](http://www.intel.com/support/chipsets/imst/sb/cs-020825.htm) that you can download [IATA88ENU.EXE](http://downloadcenter.intel.com/Detail_Desc.aspx?ProductID=2842&DwnldID=17412&lang=eng) from Intel, extract files from package which contains the the iastor.sys (albeit for an unattended install).

Comment: I've downloaded IATA88ENU.EXE. How can it be extracted?

Comment: The Intel link that I provided says: 

To extract these files, run the executable (e.g. IATA88ENU.EXE for Intel® Matrix Storage Manager version 8.8) with the following command line options: -A -A -PC:\<path>, as described in the Advanced Installation Instructions section of the README.TXT.